# Python Matplotlib: Drawing 2d line without sorting xdata

Tags: python, sorting, matplotlib, line, lexicographic-ordering

How can I tell matplotlib to **not** sort xdata given as input when drawing a matplotlib.lines.Line2D ?

I want to create custom xticks which I create as strings, for example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = ['1','2','10']
y = [ 1 , 2 ,  3 ]
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
plt.show(block=False)
```

and I get x values drawn in the order `['1','10','2']`, i.e. they get lexicographically sorted. How can I get them drawn in the original order?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Which version of `matplotlib` are you using? For me your code works just fine. In python2.x you can just try `map(int, x)`

Comment: I use matplotlib 2.1.1 with python 3.6.3. Which version do you use?

Comment: I can see two possible interpretations for what you trying to do. Can you please post a picture of the expected vs. actual results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade your matplotlib to version 2.2.0 or higher. (Current version is 2.2.2)

This will solve your problem automatically because it respects the order of the input.